# PHPUnit run callback on failed assertion

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am testing a symfony app.

when an assertion fails, I would like to see the web client HTML output.
I am seeking for a short and elegant version of this:

```
if(1 !== $crawler->filter('.flash-success')->count())
    file_put_contents("debug.html", $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.flash-success')->count());
```

My proposal is to register a callback that gets the 3rd parameter of the `assertXXX`:

```
// ideally like this
phpunit_register_callback(write_to_disk_callback);
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.flash-success')->count(), $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

In my case the callback should write the message to a file on disk, so I can open it with a browser...

```
function write_to_disk_callback($message){
    file_put_contents("debug.html", $message);
}
```

Comment: since the third parameter in `assertEquals` is for output, why not do it there? maybe as an anonymous function ...

Comment: the third parameter will be printed to stdout, but I would like to be able to process it with e.g. `write_to_disk_callback`. I want to keep the test code readable. I updated the question

Comment: how about creating a new TestCase class, that overrides all the assert[Something] methods and uses the assertion-message string to also call a callback?

Comment: Jup, that would be possible, but I would have to overwrite each and every assertion method. I was searching for a clean and already existing way to realize this...

Comment: creating a debug.html doesn't seem to be a very common case. I would probably add a function to my test case `function responseToDebug() { $content = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent(); file_put_contents("debug.html", $content); return $content; }` and then use it as `$this->assertEquals(1, [whatever], $this->responseToDebug());`

Comment: Yes, but that would dump every message with every assert. I'd like to only dump if an error occured

Comment: you're right. missed that. okay, what about only storing it in a property and write it out in the tearDown? you probably can also ask for the status of the test in the tearDown, but I'm not certain

Answer (score 3):

I think should take a look at the [phpunit listeners](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener)

Here is a little example of how you implement a listener in your SF project

First you have to create a listener:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\PHPUnit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Test;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestListenerDefaultImplementation;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SimpleTestListener implements TestListener
{
    use TestListenerDefaultImplementation;

    public function addFailure(Test $test, AssertionFailedError $e, float $time): void
    {
        if ($test instanceof WebTestCase && method_exists($test, 'getClient')) {
            /** @var Client $client */
            $client = $test->getClient();

            // Write the client response to a file
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add the listener on your phpunit.xml:

```xml
<listeners>
    ...
    <listener class="Tests\PHPUnit\SimpleTestListener"/>
</listeners>
```

Finaly, update your test file:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\PHPUnit\YesWeHack;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    static private $client;

    static public function getClient()
    {
        return static::$client;
    }

    protected static function createClient(array $options = [], array $server = [])
    {
        static::$client = parent::createClient($options, $server);

        return static::$client;
    }

    public function testReportIsFixed()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(500, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Note that the `MyTest` class is just an example and should not be use like that, It is just for the purpose example.
At least you should propably move the statics prop and methods to an abstract class that your tests will extends.

Here is the result of a simple test on a project where I dump the response code and response content in the listener:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
int(200)
string(523) "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
            </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">

    <form name="form" method="post">
        <div><label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label><input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" /></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="2AsriLX8VMS0VqomR2wtTGk159TXMhYQJlPt_Chwtv8" />
    </form>
</div>
            </body>
</html>
"
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 118 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\PHPUnit\YesWeHack\YWH_PGM5_1Test::testReportIsFixed
Failed asserting that 200 matches expected 500.

MyTest.php:29

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```